# Can Anyone Suggest a Continuous Generalization of Hamming Distance?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, mean-square-error

I'm an EE, so please forgive if this question is dumb.

I need a continuous generalization of Hamming distance. It needs to be both integrable and differentiable.

A quick Google Scholar search for "continuous hamming distance" (no quotes in search bar) did not yield anything relevant.

But I'm not a mathematician, so if there *is* a family of functions which formalizes the concept I don't even know what it might be called.

Perhaps the most obvious choice is to use MMSE:

```
        N-1
dist = sigma (x0 - x1)^2
        n=0
```

My question is twofold:

1.) Is there already a well known continuous valued generalization of Hamming distance?

2.) Has anyone rigorously studied functions of the form:

```
     N-1
y = sigma f(xn0, xn1)^p
     n=0
```

performed all the normal proofs to spell out when this function is meaningful, figured out the limit as n -> infinity, etc.

As I've said before, I'm not a mathematician, so if different tags should be used please make suggestions. Thank you so much!

Comment: Very interesting! I'd think that a `natural' generalization would be something like

$$
d_\epsilon(f,g)=\int dx \ H(|f(x)-g(x)|-\epsilon)
$$ 

Where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. This yields the length over $x$ where $f$ and $g$ differ by more than $\epsilon$. Presumably you'd then want to check which of the usual metric properties this satisfies

Comment: I like the idea! Would it cause any problems to replace Heaviside step with the logistic function?

Comment: Thanks! Since we're defining things the only problem we can encounter is if our definition has properties we don't want. Replacing $H$ by the sigmoid would result in $d(f,f)\neq0$ since $\operatorname{sigmoid}(0)\neq 0$. However, we can write down a generalization 

$$
d(f,g)=\int dx \ D(|f(x)-g(x)|)
$$

Where $D(x)$ is an increasing function with the properties...

Comment: $$
\lim_{x\to 0} D(x)=0 \\
\lim_{x\to \infty} D(x)=1
$$

I have chosen these properties so that *heurestically and non-rigorously*, $d$ behaves like the Hamming distance, ie.$d(f,f)=0 $, $ \ d(f,g) \to L$ when $f$ and $g$ are `most different' and $L$ is the length of $x$ over which $f$ and $g$ are defined. In the spirit of the sigmoid, you can choose something like $D(x)=\tanh(x)$

Comment: I just realized that because I want to take limits on this thing later, I'm pretty sure the function needs to be differentiable. So I modified the question. Anywho, that's the only reason I had any objection to Heaviside.

Comment: The Heaviside theta has the distributional derivative $\delta(x)$, Dirac's delta, but that may not be what you want... What sort of limits do you want to take?

Comment: @Sal can you copy your comments and paste them into an answer? Feel free to suggest mods to question so that the overall presentation makes sense :)

Comment: Will do later today- there is an aspect of your question that I'd still like to think about a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, summary of comments.

I think a `natural' generalization would be

$$\tag{1}
d_\epsilon(f,g)=\int dx \ H(|f(x)-g(x)|-\epsilon)
$$

Where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. This yields the length over $x$ where $f$ and $g$ differ by more than $\epsilon$. $d$ in equation (1) does not vary smoothly as $f$ and $g$ vary, as a consequence of the `coarse graining'.

If a function other than Heaviside is desired, we can write down a generalization

$$\tag{2}
d(f,g)=\int dx \ D(|f(x)-g(x)|)
$$

Where $D$ is any increasing function with the properties

$$
D(0)=0 \\
\lim_{x \to \infty}D(x)=1
$$

I have chosen these properties so that *heuristically and non-rigorously*, $d$ behaves like the Hamming distance, ie.$d(f,f)=0$,  $d(f,g)→L$ when $f$ and $g$ are `most different' and $L$ is the length of $x$ over which $f$ and $g$ are defined. $d$ in equation (2) yields a weighted length over which $f$ and $g$ differ. An example function based on the sigmoid would be

$$
D(x)=\tanh(x/\epsilon)
$$

Where now $\epsilon$ sets the length scale. As $\epsilon \to 0$, $|f-g|$ must be smaller to be considered `the same'.

The continuous version of the RMSE you mention is

$$\tag{3}
d(f-g)=\sqrt{\int dx \left(f(x)-g(x) \right)^2}
$$

which is the $L^2$ norm of $f-g$. Such metrics are well studied, the keywords to search for are $L^p$ spaces.

If you want *some* way to quantify the difference between functions, then equation (3) is convenient because it is well known and all of the proofs have already been worked out, etc. If you specifically want a way to quantify the difference between functions that is to be the analog of the Hamming metric, then you'd want to work with things like equation (1) or (2), the difficulty is then showing precisely in which way these reduce to the Hamming metric and determining if they fulfill the usual nice properties for a metric.